# How to correct data types to use gowdis function in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R and have what may be a question with an obvious answer, however, Google hasn't been much help to me yet. I am trying to generate a Gower dissimilarity matrix using different traits (i.e. traits that are categorical, continuous, and nominal). I'd like to use the gowdis() function in the FD package. When using the dummy dataset I get this:

```
ex1<-gowdis(dummy$trait)
attribute(ex1)

$Labels
[1] "sp1" "sp2" "sp3" "sp4" "sp5" "sp6" "sp7" "sp8"

$Size
[1] 8

$Metric
[1] "Gower"

$Types
[1] "C" "C" "N" "N" "O" "O" "B" "B"

$class
[1] "dist"

However, using my dataset I get this:

$Size
[1] 129

$Metric
[1] "Gower"

$Types
 [1] "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C"

$class
[1] "dist"
```

This may be an easy fix, but is there any way I can change the "type" since my traits actually aren't all "C"?

Thanks for any help.

Here is the str(mydata) :

```
'data.frame':   129 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ Identity                     : int  1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Max.length..mm.              : int  2414 205 373 427 465 297 870 1520 144     940 ...
 $ Reproductive.body.length..mm.: num  950 138 54 220 212 161 610 460 55 292 ...
 $ Age.at.Maturation            : num  18 3 3 2.5 2.5 2.5 4 10.4 2 4.5 ...
 $ Longevity                    : num  154 6 10 9 7 8 25 43 4 17 ...
 $ Fecundity                    : int  1000000 300000 11000 5495 7000 13000 64000 10000000 400 508000 ...
 $ Egg.Diameter..mm.            : num  2.9 0.9 1.8 3 2.9 3 2.8 1 1.14 1.4 ...
 $ Length.at.Hatch              : num  7.51 2.56 4.84 7.75 7.51 7.75 7.27 2.82 3.18 3.84 ...
 $ BALON_GUILD                  : int  2 4 11 11 14 14 13 1 11 1 ...
 $ Spawning.at.0to20            : int  4 4 3 4 4 3 4 4 4 3 ...
 $ Spawning.at.21to60           : int  4 4 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 3 ...
 $ Spawning.at.61to100          : int  3 4 3 3 4 3 4 4 3 3 ...
 $ Spawning.at.101to200         : int  3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 ...
 $ Spawning.at.gr200            : int  3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Spawning.Substrate.Breadth   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Bottom.Feeder                : int  1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Pelagic.Feeder               : int  4 1 1 4 4 4 1 1 1 4 ...
 $ Surface.Feeder               : int  4 4 2 4 4 4 1 4 2 4 ...
 $ Diet.Breadth                 : int  5 1 3 4 4 5 3 5 1 4 ...
```

Comment: Well what types are your traits? Show us `str(yourdata)`. The help indicates that the variables in your data can be numeric, factor, or ordered. If you have character data these will be coerced to factors first. So it would appear that you need to code your data correctly and for that you need to check your data, or show us the data (or the structure of it) and then tell us what types your traits are.

Comment: I have continuous, categorical, and nominal traits in my dataset. I added the str(data) to my original question.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks for your comment. Although you didn't directly answer my question, your comment got me thinking and pointed me in a direction by which I was able to find the answer on my own! Thanks again!